# No puedo leer las etiquetas NFC Mifare en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, nfc

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Quiero leer etiquetas NFC, en una aplicación en android studio que estoy desarrollando.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que directamente no me las lee, otro tipo de tarjetas si, pero necesito sacar el UID de las Mifare en especifico (Aclaro que si que vibra el movil pero no las detecta mi aplicación).

**JAVA**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        processNFC(getIntent());
    }

    private void processNFC(Intent intent) {
        Log.e("MENSAJES ES: ", "BIEN");
        String id = null;
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag != null) {
            byte[] idBytes = tag.getId();
            // Convierte el ID de bytes a una cadena hexadecimal
            id = bytesToHexString(idBytes);
        }

        if (id != null) {
            textView.append("ID de la tarjeta NFC: " + id + "\n");
        } else {
            textView.append("No se pudo leer el ID de la tarjeta NFC.");
        }
    }

    private String bytesToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            hexString.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }


}
```

**Activity Main XML (Layout)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.alannia.nfcreaderpro.MainActivity"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello Word!"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NFCReaderPro"
        tools:targetApi="31" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="alannia.com"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Queria saber el motivo, la causa o ayuda de alguien que se haya visto en la tesitura o este desarrollando algo parecido y se haya tropezado con este error o incapacidad.

Answer (score 0):

Inicialmente, es muy importante definir el permiso

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

[Este permiso es necesario para poder acceder al hardware y manejar los `intents` de NFC, lo cual no tienes definido en tu aplicación.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc?hl=es-419#manifest)

Además, para obtener la información de los `intents`, que se obtiene al escanear la etiqueta NFC, tienes definidos los "`intent-filter`" pero debes implementar el método [**onNewIntent()**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc?hl=es-419#obtain-info), ejemplo:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    ...
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Parcelable[] rawMessages =
            intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (rawMessages != null) {
            NdefMessage[] messages = new NdefMessage[rawMessages.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMessages.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMessages[i];
            }
            // Procesa el arreglo de mensajes.
            ...
        }
    }
}
```